# Google App Engine : GeoPtProperty query

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this `latlng = db.GeoPtProperty()` in app engine.

Given a lat long, how do I query the first 10 closer latlng without using any third party library?

Is there any nice documentation for me to refer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geospatial queries aren't supported natively by the datastore. There are userland implementations however, including geomodel, documented [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geospatial.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is natively supported yet.  However, there is a talk at [Google I/O 2011](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions.html) on App Engine full text search (emphasis mine):

> "At last we are adding a full text
>   search service to App Engine. The
>   upcoming service will be built on top
>   of the very infrastructure used by
>   Google. In addition to full text
>   search queries we will also offer
>   numeric, **geo**, date search
>   capabilities, and much more. This
>   session will cover the basic full text
>   search API, briefly outline more
>   advanced features, and how full text
>   search ties to existing services such
>   as datastore."

Stay tuned...

Comment: 2 years later... Has this been implemented? Haven't found anything yet.